# Broken Pipe exception when trying to write a file

Tags: java, http, sockets

I'm trying to write a pretty simple application which will upload a video to one of my server over HTTP with a PUT request. Here's what my code looks like:

```
socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ticket.getHost(), 80));

outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

// begin forming the request
outputStream.write(("PUT " + ticket.getEndpoint() + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
        "Host: " + ticket.getHost() + "\r\n" + 
        "Content-Length: " + getStreamFile().length() + "\r\n" +
        "Content-Type: video/mp4\r\n\r\n").getBytes());

// now, let's write us some binary data
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(getStreamFile());
inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);

byte[] fileBytes = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead = 0;
int totalBytesRead = 0;

while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(fileBytes)) > 0) {
    outputStream.write(fileBytes, 0, bytesRead);

    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

    notifyListenersOnProgress((double)totalBytesRead / (double)getStreamFile().length());
}
```

Pretty simple, right? Right until I see this error after about two loops:

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_23]   
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.6.0_23]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this stuff by hand. Use HttpURLConnection for this, that's what it's for. Create a URL, get the HttpURLConnection from it, set the request method to "PUT", set the content-type, *don't* set the content-length, get the output stream, and start writing.

Comment: Due to upload requirements, I _have to_ set the content length. Will I be able to write like normal to the output stream so I can measure upload progress?

Comment: @TKKocheran No you don't. Java will set the content length automatically. Setting it yourself only provides an opportunity to get it wrong. If it's a large transfer I would set chunked transfer mode. Yes you can monitor progress to the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem, but you're missing a second `\r\n` after `video/mp4`.

You should also modify your `write` call to write only the first `bytesRead` bytes of your array.

Comment: Fixed and fixed, and still getting a broken pipe.

Comment: Split your output to a file as well and check it.  I like to use a `TeeOutputStream` from apache commons.  Make sure your ticket.getEndpoint() is right (e.g. no `http://host.com` prefix).

Comment: What should the `ticket.getEndpoint()` result look like? Should it be a fully formed URL or just a relative one to the site root?

Comment: @TK: it should be relative to the site root (e.g. `/index.html`).

Answer (score 0):

The receiving end of the socket closed the connection for some reason.

Comment: Your first sentence is correct, but the rest is not. `Socket.isConnected()` won't detect that. It isn't a connection status, it is a socket status.